# Delay Wordpress Function 2 seconds After Page Load

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a working function to show a best selling badge on product archive pages however it crashes my site with the amount of look ups it has to do

so can I delay this function by 2 seconds so that the page loads first and then the functions runs or is there a better way to do it

```
// add trending block to loop page

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title',     'wc_product_sold_count_last_week_loop', 11 );

function wc_product_sold_count_last_week_loop() {

global $product;
$product_id = $product->get_ID();

// Get last week orders for specified product
$all_orders = wc_get_orders(
array(
'limit' => -1,
'status' => array_map( 'wc_get_order_status_name', wc_get_is_paid_statuses() ),
'date_after' => date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( '-1 week' ) ),
'return' => 'ids',
'meta_query' => array(
array(
'key' => '_product_id',
'value' => $product_id,
),
),
)
);

// Sum quantities purchased for specified product
$count = 0;
foreach ( $all_orders as $all_order ) {
$order = wc_get_order( $all_order );
$items = $order->get_items();
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    if ( $item->get_product_id() == $product_id ) {
        $count = $count + absint( $item['qty'] );
    }
}
}

// Display sales for specified product
if ( $count > 20 ) {
echo "<div class='trending-block-loop'><svg width='16' height='16' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><path d='M8.625 0c.61 7.189-5.625 9.664-5.625 15.996 0 4.301 3.069 7.972 9 8.004 5.931.032 9-4.414 9-8.956 0-4.141-2.062-8.046-5.952-10.474.924 2.607-.306 4.988-1.501 5.808.07-3.337-1.125-8.289-4.922-10.378zm4.711 13c3.755 3.989 1.449 9-1.567 9-1.835 0-2.779-1.265-2.769-2.577.019-2.433 2.737-2.435 4.336-6.423z'/></svg> Selling Fast</div>";
}
}
```

argos website in uk has similar function and this seems to load after the page has fully loaded ...

https://www.argos.co.uk/search/screwdriver/

Comment: No, you can't "delay" this, as long as it is part of the page generation process. You would need to "outsource" this into some sort of endpoint, and then request it after the page has loaded, via AJAX.

Comment: But a different question would be, if this whole process needs to execute on every page load to begin with. The result could probably get cached for a while. (Keyword _Transients API_.)

Comment: @CBroe any solution on how to do this? #noob

Comment: You should [schedule an event](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/) (or do a daily CRON job, at night) which would look up best selling products from most recent orders and store the results in the database (either as an array of best selling products, or perhaps assign a custom `is_bestseller` postmeta for these products). Then, in `woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title` action you'd need a simple `get_post_meta()` check. There might be even more elegant solution, this is just off the top of my head.